# Why doesn't this example using Future run faster then the benchmark?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand `Future`s, so I wrote a `Summer` class that divides a list, executes it in n-different futures, and combines the results. It's more then 5x slower then a non-divided version, and I'd like to know why. Here's my benchmark:

```
import java.util.Date

object SummerMain {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val xs = List.fill(10000000)(1)

        println("Starting")

        val t = Timer()
        val x = xs.foldLeft(0)(_+_)
        val time = t.stop

        println(s"Sum: ${x}, time: ${time} ms")
    }
}

case class Timer(startTime: Long = new Date().getTime) {
    private def curMs: Long = new Date().getTime

    def restart: Timer = Timer(curMs)
    def stop: Long = curMs - startTime
    def lap: (Long, Timer) = { val curTime = curMs
        (curTime - startTime,Timer(curTime))
    }

}
```

This runs on average in about 790 ms.

But this takes around 4.5 seconds:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object SummerMain {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        val s = Summer(
                    xs = List.fill(10000000)(1),
                    nParts = 5 // The number of futures to divide it over
                )

        println("Starting")

        val t = Timer()
        val x = s.breakSum
        val time = t.stop

        println(s"Sum: ${x}, time: ${time} ms")
    }
}

case class Summer(xs: List[Int], nParts: Int) {
    lazy val elemsPer = (xs.length / nParts) + 1

    def sum(xs: List[Int]): Long =
        xs.foldLeft(0)(_+_)

    def break(ys: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = ys match {
        case Nil    => List()
        case zs     => (zs take elemsPer) :: break(zs drop elemsPer)
    }

    def breakSum: Long = {
        val futures: List[Future[Long]] = break(xs) map { ys =>
                Future( sum(ys) )
        }

        var s: Long = 0L

        for ( f <- futures ) {
            s += Await.result(f, 10 hours)
        }

        s
    }
}
```

Is my algorithm so inefficient that it's making up for the gain, or am I using `Future` incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operation you are trying to parallelize is **very fast**.

Basically, it simply takes the time of going through of all the elements since `+` on integer takes only 1 CPU cycle. Unbeatable.

The problem is that the operation of just breaking up the original list takes more time than just summing all the elements: you need to allocate new memory **and** you need to go through all the elements of the list (to put them in the new lists), which is what was sufficient to get the result in the first place!

Once the list is split, submitting the `Runnable`s trigger the creation of 5 threads, which is an operation that is not free, thus bringing a new overhead. Only then, the parallelization ***might*** be faster that the non-concurrent version.

Parallelization is mostly interesting when parallelizing on costly operations. On fast operations, it might be preferable to use all the power of one CPU and use other ones to do other operations in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

### The problem

The `break` method is extremely inefficient.

```
case zs     => (zs take elemsPer) :: break(zs drop elemsPer)
```

This piece of code creates two new lists which itself takes more time than simply summing the items.

### A possible solution

Store the numbers in an indexed structure (such as an Array or IndexedSeq), and pass a starting and ending index to each thread. The threads should calculate the sum between the given indices, but from the **same** collection.

### Room for improvement

```
    for ( f <- futures ) {
        s += Await.result(f, 10 hours)
    }
```

The above code could be improved to utilise maximum parallelism.

`Future.reduce` combines results as they arrive, which may give a better result:

```
val sum = Future.reduce(futures)(_ + _)
Await.result(sum, 10 hours)
```

Comment: Aren't the futures started on the call to `Future`?

Comment: Yeah they should be, for standard scala `Future`.

Comment: So, most of the problem is the algorithm, not the use of futures?

Comment: I'll time it separately and see what percentage it is (which I guess I could have done from the start).

Comment: You should always inspect how much overhead it causes to introduce parallelism (threads always involve some overhead eg. due to context switching, but if your task is in the multi-ms range, it is negligible). In your case the performance drop is not (only) caused by threads, but because you are cloning huge collections.

Comment: @David Thanks. The break function alone accounts for 86% of the time, so that explains it.

Comment: @DavidFrank Do you have any idea why when I add the line `val sum = Future.reduce(futures)(_+_)`, I get an error on `Future ( sum(ys) )`: `scala.concurrent.Future[Long] does not take parameters`?

Comment: Nvm, it's caused by a name conflict -_-

Comment: Using `Future.reduce` gave me a 12% increase in speed.

Comment: If you think, my answer satisfies your needs, please accept it, so other users can see that this is the correct answer.